# How do I repeat this start() function and get it to not break in the middle of a loop?

Tags: python, robotics

I've been trying to get this code to repeat the start function and it just keeps stopping before my "gohome()" function and the of my "gomine()" function... Maybe you guys can see something I'm not seeing?
Also, I'm using Python 2 in this weird IDE.

```py
def takeoff():
 robot2.takeOff(5)
 robot2.moveForward(23)
 robot2.setAltitude(2)
 
def gomine(i):
 print len(vrad_comms.getMines())
 while len(vrad_comms.getMines()) <= i:
     i+=1
 targetMine = vrad_comms.getMines()[i];
 k=0
 while k<3:
     k+=1
     angle = float(robot2.getAngleTo(targetMine[0], targetMine[1]))
     if (angle < 0.0):
         robot2.turnLeft(abs(angle))
     else: 
         robot2.turnRight(angle)
     dist = robot2.getDistanceTo(targetMine[0], targetMine[1])
     robot2.moveForward(dist)
     robot2.setAltitude(0)
     robot2.mine()

def gohome():
 print "go home"
 robot2.takeOff(7.0)
 m=0
 while m<2:
     m+=1
     angle=float(robot2.getAngleTo(home[0],home[2]))
     if (angle < 0.0):
         robot2.turnLeft(abs(angle))
     else:
         robot2.turnRight(angle)
     angle = float(robot2.getAngleTo(home[0], home[2]))
     dist = robot2.getDistanceTo(home[0], home[2])
     robot2.moveForward(dist)
     error = robot2.getDistanceTo(home[0], home[2])
     robot2.turnRight(180)
     robot2.land()
     robot2.deposit()
     print "Deposited"
     
def start():
 takeoff()
 gomine(i)
 gohome()
 
t=0
if t<5:
 t+=1
 start()
 print "Robot 2 is on their way again"
```

Comment: Replace if with while. If does not loop, it just tests the condition once. But it's better to use a for loop here anyway.

Comment: How would the for loop look like? I've tried using whille True, but it does the same thing and stops after it deposits. Here is what I used `while True: start()` @ScienceSnake

Comment: No, that will just lead to a loop that never stop. Put the condition in the loop, so in this case, ```while  t < 5:``` Generally, I'd recommend you follow some basic online tutorial and exercises to learn the fundamental concepts before trying your own thing. The few hours of investment will pay off handsomely.

Comment: This problem is so troubling though @ScienceSnake. The robot just completely stops after its first deposit and it doesn't go out again...